# Pandas apply, how to combine the results returned

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, apply

In python pandas apply, the applied function takes each row of the Dataframe and will return another Dataframe, how can I get the combination of (append) these Dataframes returned through applying? For example:

```
# this is an example

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def newdata(X, data2):
    return X - data2[data2['no']!=X['no']].sample(1,random_state=100)

col = ['no','a','b']
data1 = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((range(5),np.random.rand(5,2))),columns=col)
data2 = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((range(3),np.random.rand(3,2))),columns=col)
Newdata = data1.apply(newdata, args=(data2,), axis=1)
```

Comment: Maybe show a sample of what the old data looks like, and what the new data *should* look like

Comment: Thx, data will be added.

Comment: At first I looped through the rows, it worked but seemed very slow. Hope the 'apply' method will be better